# Iterate on tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to perform the same operation on several tables. Right now the query looks like this:

```
create view foobar
as 
select this, that 
from here 
where this=1 
union all 
select this,that 
from there 
where this=1
..... .....
```

and so on, for several tables. All the results are union-ed.

Is there a way to, instead of writing this very long query where it's easy to get something wrong, to write something like

```
for table in here, there, upthere
 do
 select this, that from $table where this=1
```

and then take the union of them all.

I have the query working right now and it's going to take a while, but this is just curiosity and I didn't know how to search for this on Google!

Comment: Sounds like you should have in fact a single table instead of several.

Comment: @horse Each table here, there, upthere etc, contain information which is being matched, in the real situation, against another table, let's call it sumup. Whoever does not match (ie. is not in the sumup) is in foobar. Does this clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `VIEW` from `UNION` of all tables you need and then `SELECT` from this `VIEW`.

Additionally you can create a `VIEW` like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table_set AS
SELECT 'table1' as table_name, field1, field2 ...
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' as table_name, field1, field2 ...
FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table3' as table_name, field1, field2 ...
FROM table3
UNION ALL
...
```

and `SELECT` from this `VIEW` like:

```
SELECT field1, field3
FROM table_set
WHERE table_name IN ('table2','table4')
  AND field5 = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

A **view** [like @Igor desrcibes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632660/939860) is one option.

If performance is of the essence and you don't have a lot of write operations, you could use that view to (re-)create a [**materialized view**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_View#Materialized_View).

Or, for shorter syntax and dynamic selection of source tables, you could utilize a **plpgsql function** like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_select_from_tbls(tables text[], cond int)
  RETURNS TABLE (this int, that text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   tbl text; -- automatically avoids SQLi
BEGIN
   FOREACH tbl IN ARRAY tables LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT this, that
      FROM   %I
      WHERE  this = $1', tbl)
      USING cond;
   END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_select_from_tbls('{t1,t2,nonStandard tablename}', 4);
```

I assume a number of tables sharing columns of the same name and type `(this int, that text)` (You didn't define the data types in you question.) The function takes an `array of text` as tables names and an `integer` value as condition.

More about [Looping Through Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) in the manual.
More about [Returning From a Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in the manual.

With dynamic SQL you have to be wary of **SQL injection**. That threat is neutralized here in two ways:

- Table names in the array `tables` are injected with the function [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) which properly quotes any non-standard table name
- The value in parameter `cond` is passed in as is via `USING`, thereby making SQLi impossible.

#### Variant with [`VARIADIC` parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

The purpose is to make the function call simpler. You can hand in a list of text variables instead of building an array from them (array is built internally from the parameters). That's all.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_select_from_tbls2(cond int, VARIADIC tables text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (this int, that text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   tbl text; -- automatically avoids SQLi
BEGIN
   FOREACH tbl IN ARRAY tables LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT this, that
      FROM   %I
      WHERE  this = $1', tbl)
      USING cond;
   END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I placed `tables` last in this case to have an open end for the `VARIADIC` parameter.
Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_select_from_tbls2(4, 't1','t2','iLLegal name')
```